# Out of 4 methods for Document Question Answering in LangChain, which one if the fastest and why (ignoring the LLM model used)?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3, langchain

**NOTE:**: My *reference document* data changes periodically so if I use Embedding Vector space method, I have to Modify the embedding, say once a day

I want to know these factors so that I can design my system to compensate my *reference document data* generation latency with creating embedding beforehand using Cron Jobs

There are 4 methods in `LangChain` using which we can retrieve the QA over Documents. More or less they are wrappers over one another.

1. `load_qa_chain` uses Dynamic Document each time it's called
2. `RetrievalQA` get it from the Embedding space of document
3. `VectorstoreIndexCreator` is the wrapper of `2.`
4. `ConversationalRetrievalChain` uses Embedding Space and it has a memory and chat history too.

What is the difference between `1,3,4` in terms of speed?

1. If I use embedding DB, would it be faster than `load_qa_chain` assuming that making Embedding of the document beforehand (like in `2,3`)helps or is it same because the time taken for a 50 words Prompt is same as Time taken for a 2000 words (Document Text + Prompt in `load_qa_chain`) ?
2. Will the speed be affected If I use `ConversationalRetrievalChain` with or without `memory` and `chat_history`?

Answer (score 1):

- **load_qa_chain** uses all texts and accepts multiple documents;
- **RetrievalQA** uses load_qa_chain under the hood but retrieves relevant text chunks first;
- **VectorstoreIndexCreator** is the same as RetrievalQA with a higher-level interface;
- **ConversationalRetrievalChain** is useful when you want to pass in your chat history to the model.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your question one, the answer could be very various, depending on the `LLM` that using `load_qa_chain` to run against and/ or local `VectorStore` performance by indexing of `VectorstoreIndexCreator`. Generally, I think the time taken for `VectorstoreIndexCreator` and `VectorStoreRetriever` should be *longer* than `load_qa_chain`, as my experience in project.

For your 2nd question, I think `ConversationalRetrievalChain` speed will be different in between with and without memory and `chat_history`. If we look at the function >

`qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), vectorstore.as_retriever(), memory=memory)`

from document >

https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/chat_vector_db

`as_retriever` would definitely take time to create index and load the history